# Combobox selection and Model binding

Tags: java, mysql, javafx, combobox, model

**Problem overview:**

I have two models `OrderModel` and `OrderStatusModel`.  The `OrderStatusModel` items are put into a combobox that contains choices for the user to update a foreign key field in an `Order` table called `orderStatusId`. When I initialize the data, I want to be able to pull from `OrderModel` and retrieve the current `orderStatusId` and then set the combobox (that holds all the user choices) to  match the `orderStatusId` located in the `OrderModel`(which holds the FK located in the `Order` table).  The combobox needs to be able to update the `OrderModel` when a new selection is made. While getting data from a database to populate the `OrderModel`, I pull my FK `orderStatusId`.  From this point I use case statements to select the appropriate item in `OrderStatusModel` and select the choice on initialization.   I know this can't be the greatest method because if I were to add a new row in the backend database for a new type of status (for example: order cancelled) then I need to go and update all my switch statements to allow for that change.

**Example Code**

`Controller`

```
package test.pkg2;

import java.awt.Label;
import java.beans.Statement;
import java.net.URL;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.util.ResourceBundle;
import javafx.collections.FXCollections;
import javafx.collections.ObservableList;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.fxml.Initializable;
import javafx.scene.control.ComboBox;

public class Test2Controller implements Initializable{

    @FXML
    private Label customerName;

    @FXML
    private Label orderNumber;

    @FXML
    private Label orderStatusId;

    @FXML
    private ComboBox<OrderStatusModel> orderStatusCmb;

    private ObservableList<OrderStatusModel> orderStatusModel;
    private ObservableList<OrderModel> orderModel;

    int statusId;

    @Override
    public void initialize(URL location, ResourceBundle resources) {
        this.orderStatusCmb.getSelectionModel().selectedItemProperty().addListener((obs, newValue, oldValue) ->{
            if(newValue != null && newValue != oldValue){
                this.orderStatusCmb.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItem().getOrderStatusId();
                //TODO UPDATE Order table with new orderStatusId from above code ^^^^^^
            }
        });
        populateOrderStatusCombobox();
        getCurrentOrder();
    }

    private void populateOrderStatusCombobox(){
        String SQL = "SELECT Status.statusId, Status.statusName \n" 
                     +"FROM Status;";

        orderStatusModel = FXCollections.observableArrayList();

        //Status table:
        // +-----------+-------------+------+-----+---------+
        // | Field     | Type        | Null | Key | Default |
        // +-----------+-------------+------+-----+---------+
        // | statusId  | int         | YES  | PK  | NULL    |       
        // | statusName| varchar(20) | YES  |     | NULL    |       
        // +-----------+-------------+------+-----+---------+

        //example data: statusId = 1 statusName = Order Taken
        //example data: statusId = 2 statusName = Order Processing
        //example data: statusId = 3 statusName = Shipped

        //Above items are populated into the combobox for selection
        try(Connection connection = DBConnection.getConnection()){
            PreparedStatement statement = connection.prepareStatement(SQL);
            ResultSet resultSet = statement.executeQuery();
            while(resultSet.next()){
                this.orderStatusModel.add(new OrderStatusModel(resultSet.getInt("statusId"),
                                                    resultSet.getString("statusName")));
            }
        } catch(SQLException e){

        }
        this.orderStatusCmb.setItems(orderStatusModel);
    }
    private void getCurrentOrder(){
        String SQL = "SELECT Order.orderNumber, Order.customerName, Order.orderStatusId \n"
                    +"FROM Order"
                    +"WHERE orderNumber = 123;";
        orderModel = FXCollections.observableArrayList();

        //Order table:
        // +--------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+
        // | Field        | Type        | Null | Key | Default |
        // +--------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+
        // | orderNumber  | int         | YES  | PK  | NULL    |       
        // | customerName | varchar(20) | YES  |     | NULL    |       
        // | orderStatusId| int         | YES  | FK  | NULL    |  
        // +--------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+

        //example data: orderNumber = 123
        //              customerName = SomeCompany
        //              orderStatusId = 1

        //I usually set the combobox here using the below method:
        try(Connection connection = DBConnection.getConnection()){
            PreparedStatement statement = connection.prepareStatement(SQL);
            ResultSet resultSet = statement.executeQuery();
            while(resultSet.next()){
                this.orderModel.add(new OrderModel(resultSet.getInt("orderNumber"),
                                                    resultSet.getString("customerName"),
                                                    resultSet.getInt("orderStatusId")));
                                                    statusId = resultSet.getInt("orderStatusId");
            }

            //HERE is where I initially set the orderStatus to match the orderModel
            //I am guessing I need some kind of binding here?
           switch(statusId){
               case 1: this.orderStatusCmb.getSelectionModel().select(0);
               break;
               case 2: this.orderStatusCmb.getSelectionModel().select(1);
               break;
               case 3: this.orderStatusCmb.getSelectionModel().select(3);
               break;
           }
        } catch(SQLException e){

        }
    }
}
```

`OrderStatusModel`

```
import javafx.beans.property.IntegerProperty;
import javafx.beans.property.SimpleIntegerProperty;
import javafx.beans.property.SimpleStringProperty;
import javafx.beans.property.StringProperty;


public class OrderStatusModel {
    private final IntegerProperty orderStatusId;
    private final StringProperty orderStatusName;

    public OrderStatusModel(int orderStatusId, String orderStatusName){
        this.orderStatusId = new SimpleIntegerProperty(orderStatusId);
        this.orderStatusName = new SimpleStringProperty(orderStatusName);
    }

    public IntegerProperty getOrderStatusId() {
        return orderStatusId;
    }

    public StringProperty getOrderStatusName() {
        return orderStatusName;
    }
}
```

`OrderModel`

```
package test.pkg2;

import javafx.beans.property.IntegerProperty;
import javafx.beans.property.SimpleIntegerProperty;
import javafx.beans.property.SimpleStringProperty;
import javafx.beans.property.StringProperty;

public class OrderModel {

    private final IntegerProperty orderNumber;
    private final StringProperty customerName;
    private final IntegerProperty orderStatusId;

    public OrderModel(int orderNumber, String customerName, int orderStatusId){
        this.orderNumber = new SimpleIntegerProperty(orderNumber);
        this.customerName = new SimpleStringProperty(customerName);
        this.orderStatusId = new SimpleIntegerProperty(orderStatusId);
    }

    public IntegerProperty getOrderNumber() {
        return orderNumber;
    }

    public StringProperty getCustomerName() {
        return customerName;
    }

    public IntegerProperty getOrderStatusId() {
        return orderStatusId;
    }
}
```

Comment: What is your question?   Are you asking for somebody to write the code which replaces the "TODO" comment and where you write "I am guessing I need some kind of binding here?"?

Comment: @jewelsea I will check these and see if this will work.  I am trying to figure out what I can do as an alternative to using a use case.  The big issue I have with what I am currently doing is that if I make any database change I have to change a lot of code which is not good practice from my understanding. In the section that says "I am guessing I need some kind of binding here?" I thought that some way to bind the two models together might work because I have seen other posts do something... remotely similar.  Thank you for your post and advice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to use any explicit binding to achieve a link between choices and IDs.  Instead, backing the combobox by your OrderStatusModel object, which already includes both the ID and friendly string name, then applying an appropriate StringConverter to the combobox will achieve a nice display of the combobox. The id -> friendly name link is still retained in the model class, which can be used in reverse in subsequent database updates as needed.

**Sample**

What this sample does is a few things:

- Extracts database interaction to an interface.
- Provides an example in-memory implementation of the database interface (replace this with an implementation that performs your actual database access code).
- Defines the database access in a separate class, which moves its logic out of your UI code so that you can more easily independently develop it, test it and swap out its implementation logic (which is all pretty much preferable, even for a small app).
- Defines the UI layout in code rather than FXML (using FXML is preferable, but creating it in the code was just for this sample to keep the code relatively short).
- Updates the naming convention for the accessors on the model classes to xxxProperty() rather than getXXX(), which is what you were using.  Anything which returns a property should have a name suffix of Property by standard JavaFX naming convention.  getXXX() methods are for retrieving the actual values of properties, not the properties themselves.
- In the OrderModel, the order status is recorded as ObjectProperty, this makes the OrderModel easier to use as it includes within it all of the relevant status information, without requiring joins and queries to get additional info.  I know it's not represented that way in your database system, but having the database interface class do the transform and return the all of the relevant info is usually a better way to go for a case like this.
- When working with the ComboBox, uses the valueProperty rather than the selectedItemProperty, as valueProperty is a more direct representation of the value of the ComboBox (doesn't matter much in this case where the user always chooses from a select drop-down and can not text edit the value portion, but still, it is a little more direct conceptually to just work with the value).
- A StringConverter is defined for the combobox which will translate the OrderStatusModel values to their friendly String names for display in the combobox.
- Defines equals and hashcode for the OrderStatusModel so that it can be properly compared and inserted into sets with the Java collections APIs using appropriate matching and duplicate logic (which, otherwise, they may not act as you expect).

*Sample Output*

[image: sample output]

*ComboApp.java*

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.geometry.Insets;
import javafx.geometry.Pos;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.ComboBox;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.layout.HBox;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.util.StringConverter;

import java.util.Optional;

public class ComboApp extends Application {
    private Label orderNumber = new Label();
    private Label customerName = new Label();
    private ComboBox<OrderStatusModel> orderStatus = new ComboBox<>();

    private Database database = new InMemoryTestDatabase();

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception {
        HBox layout = new HBox(
                10, 
                orderNumber, 
                customerName, 
                orderStatus
        );
        layout.setPadding(new Insets(10));
        layout.setAlignment(Pos.BASELINE_LEFT);

        populateOrderStatusCombobox();
        showOrder(123);
        updateOrderWhenStatusChanged();

        stage.setScene(new Scene(layout));
        stage.show();
    }

    private void updateOrderWhenStatusChanged() {
        orderStatus.valueProperty().addListener((observable, oldValue, newValue) -> {
            if (newValue != null && !newValue.equals(oldValue)) {
                database.updateOrder(
                        new OrderModel(
                                Integer.parseInt(orderNumber.getText()),
                                customerName.getText(),
                                orderStatus.getValue()
                        )
                );

                System.out.println(
                        "Updated order status of order "
                                + orderNumber.getText()
                                + " to "
                                + orderStatus.getValue()
                                    .orderStatusNameProperty()
                                    .getValue()
                );
            }
        });
    }

    private void populateOrderStatusCombobox(){
        orderStatus.setPlaceholder(new Label("None Selected"));
        orderStatus.getItems().setAll(database.listAllOrderStatuses());

        orderStatus.setConverter(new StringConverter<OrderStatusModel>() {
            @Override
            public String toString(OrderStatusModel orderStatusModel) {
                return orderStatusModel.orderStatusNameProperty().get();
            }

            @Override
            public OrderStatusModel fromString(String orderStatusName) {
                Optional<OrderStatusModel> result = database.findOrderStatusWithName(
                        orderStatusName
                );

                return result.orElse(null);
            }
        });
    }

    private void showOrder(int orderId){
        Optional<OrderModel> result = database.findOrderById(orderId);

        if (!result.isPresent()) {
            orderNumber.setText("");
            customerName.setText("");
            orderStatus.setValue(null);

            return;
        }

        OrderModel order = result.get();

        orderNumber.setText("" + order.orderNumberProperty().get());
        customerName.setText(order.customerNameProperty().get());
        orderStatus.setValue(order.orderStatusProperty().get());
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

*Database.java*

```
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Optional;

public interface Database {
    List<OrderStatusModel> listAllOrderStatuses();
    Optional<OrderStatusModel> findOrderStatusWithName(String orderStatusName);
    Optional<OrderStatusModel> findOrderStatusById(int orderStatusId);
    Optional<OrderModel> findOrderById(int orderId);
    void updateOrder(OrderModel order);
}
```

*InMemoryTestDatabase.java*

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Optional;

public class InMemoryTestDatabase implements Database {
    List<OrderStatusModel> orderStatuses = new ArrayList<>();
    List<OrderModel> orders = new ArrayList<>();

    public InMemoryTestDatabase() {
        // populate with dummy sample data.
        orderStatuses.add(new OrderStatusModel(1, "Order Taken"));
        orderStatuses.add(new OrderStatusModel(2, "Order Processing"));
        orderStatuses.add(new OrderStatusModel(3, "Shipped"));

        orders.add(
                new OrderModel(
                        123,
                        "XYZZY",
                        findOrderStatusById(1)
                                .orElse(null)
                )
        );
    }

    public List<OrderStatusModel> listAllOrderStatuses() {
        return orderStatuses;
    }

    @Override
    public Optional<OrderStatusModel> findOrderStatusWithName(String orderStatusName) {
        return orderStatuses.stream()
                .filter(orderStatus -> orderStatusName.equals(orderStatus.orderStatusNameProperty().get()))
                .findFirst();
    }

    @Override
    public Optional<OrderStatusModel> findOrderStatusById(int orderStatusId) {
        return orderStatuses.stream()
                .filter(orderStatus -> orderStatusId == orderStatus.orderStatusIdProperty().get())
                .findFirst();
    }

    public Optional<OrderModel> findOrderById(int orderId) {
        return orders.stream()
                .filter(order -> orderId == order.orderNumberProperty().get())
                .findFirst();
    }

    public void updateOrder(OrderModel order) {
        for (int i = 0; i < orders.size(); i++) {
            if (orders.get(i).orderNumberProperty().get() == order.orderNumberProperty().get()) {
                orders.set(i, order);
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

*OrderModel.java*

```
import javafx.beans.property.*;

public class OrderModel {

    private final IntegerProperty orderNumber;
    private final StringProperty customerName;
    private final ObjectProperty<OrderStatusModel> orderStatus;

    public OrderModel(int orderNumber, String customerName, OrderStatusModel orderStatus){
        this.orderNumber = new SimpleIntegerProperty(orderNumber);
        this.customerName = new SimpleStringProperty(customerName);
        this.orderStatus = new SimpleObjectProperty<>(orderStatus);
    }

    public IntegerProperty orderNumberProperty() {
        return orderNumber;
    }

    public StringProperty customerNameProperty() {
        return customerName;
    }

    public ObjectProperty<OrderStatusModel> orderStatusProperty() {
        return orderStatus;
    }
}
```

*OrderStatusModel.java*

```
import javafx.beans.property.IntegerProperty;
import javafx.beans.property.SimpleIntegerProperty;
import javafx.beans.property.SimpleStringProperty;
import javafx.beans.property.StringProperty;

import java.util.Objects;

public class OrderStatusModel {
    private final IntegerProperty orderStatusId;
    private final StringProperty orderStatusName;

    public OrderStatusModel(int orderStatusId, String orderStatusName){
        this.orderStatusId = new SimpleIntegerProperty(orderStatusId);
        this.orderStatusName = new SimpleStringProperty(orderStatusName);
    }

    public IntegerProperty orderStatusIdProperty() {
        return orderStatusId;
    }

    public StringProperty orderStatusNameProperty() {
        return orderStatusName;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if (this == o) return true;
        if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass()) return false;
        OrderStatusModel that = (OrderStatusModel) o;
        return Objects.equals(orderStatusId.get(), that.orderStatusId.get()) &&
                Objects.equals(orderStatusName.get(), that.orderStatusName.get());
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return Objects.hash(orderStatusId.get(), orderStatusName.get());
    }
}
```

**Background**

This answer was loosely based on a similar question and answer from a JavaFX forum post, which related to ChoiceBoxes rather than ComboBoxes:

- [ChoiceBox with Database IDs forum post](https://community.oracle.com/thread/2318696?tstart=0).
- [ChoiceBox with Database IDs sample code](https://gist.github.com/jewelsea/1422104).

However, this answer is updated to work directly with ComboBoxes rather than ChoiceBoxes.

**Unrelated Advice**

A couple of unrelated bits of advice about your posted code:

- Never catch an exception without rethrowing it, taking action on it or logging it.  Even if it is just for example code posted on the internet, don't do it.
- You import `java.awt.Label` which you then try to inject using FXML: that's not right, you should use `javafx.scene.control.Label`.  Don't mix awt code and JavaFX code.

Comment: Your example answer was very helpful. Thank you for your in-depth explanations.

Comment: I see all the items that I can improve upon; adding polymorphism, proper naming conventions, better use of OOP practices but there is still one part of your solution I don't 100% understand.  Taking your example, `orders.add(new OrderModel(123, "XYZZY", orderStatuses.get(0)));`  I understand I can manipulate which status is chosen from this line of code but I need to select based on the order status ID number not on the array index.  I need be able to correctly initialize the combobox based on the status ID pulled from the database. Maybe I am missing something?

Comment: With how it is setup currently, as far as I can tell, I would still be required to use a switch case statement in order to select the correct index of `orderStatuses`.  What I was trying to achieve was a more direct way based on the `orderStatusId`.

Comment: There are no switch statements in the code and there are is no need to add any.  The line you reference was just for initializing dummy test data.  I edited the answer and added a sample database method for `findOrderStatusById()` and used that when initializing the dummy test data, perhaps that makes things clearer for you.  Perhaps a key point you are missing is that in an SQL implementation, the database would return an OrderModel object and perform a join on it at that time (based upon the order status id) to generate an OrderModel which references an OrderStatusModel, not an integer id.

Comment: Well, that does solve my problem.  I just need to do more research to understand it better.  Thanks again.